# Where can I find the cause for 'Soft Error' when MC fails to create a Task?

Tags: marketing-cloud, tasks

I am trying to create Tasks in Sales Cloud, from within a Marketing Cloud journey, but sometimes it doesn't succeed. In one instance, the journey creates 100 tasks, but another 9 fail due to 'Soft Error'. There is no Status Detail.

Looking at the Contacts, for which the tasks are supposed to be created, I cannot find anything wrong, they look just like the other Contacts for which tasks could be created.

Where can I find more detail on why these task creations are failing?

Answer (score 2):

Ask SF support - they can review the backend error logs, but it might be a lot data for them to sift through.

I have heard about errors like this and at times it was due to CPU overload of the connected SF org, for example:

> System.Exception: message = "TaskTrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded",
> statusCode = "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY"

If this would be the case, try adding wait steps and random splits before the Task creation activity - this should attempt to create smaller numbers of Tasks simultaneously, reducing the CPU load.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to look up the exact error message anywhere, but according to the documentation, you can try troubleshooting using this information:

> **Runtime Errors**
>
> Runtime errors occur when a contact enters an activity in a running
> journey. In some situations, these contacts aren’t processed
> correctly. It is difficult to detect these errors because Sales and
> Service Cloud activities in Journey Builder use soft errors. A soft
> error does not stop the contact from continuing through the journey.
> Here are some common runtime errors.
>
> - Missing or deleted objects: When an object referenced in the activity is no longer available after the journey is activated, the
>   activity cannot complete its function.
> - Row-locking: Some objects, especially CampaignMember, can time out when a contact record locks and the operation stalls.
> - Failed Lookups: Sales and Service Cloud activities include options for how to proceed when a lookup fails to find a contact record.
>   However, it is possible that the lookup request can fail during
>   processing. When the request fails, the activity errors, but the
>   contact continues in the journey.
> - Required Fields: If the selected attribute for a required field is empty, the activity errors.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_sales_service_activity_validation_error.htm&type=5